# How to place my submit button bottom left relative to my form?

Tags: html, css, layout, alignment

My form is centered and I would like to place the submit button under the bottom left of my form. How can I do that?

My current code:

```css
.bio {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.send {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" class="bio">
  <input type="submit" class="send" value="Send">
</form>
```

[Here's what I want basically.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSV1y.png)

Comment: use a textarea for .bio if it has to be long text and line breaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Center the `form` instead, like so:

```css
.form {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px;
}

.bio {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 120px;
    resize: none;
    padding: 8px;
}

.send {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    padding: 4px 16px;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
<textarea class="bio" placeholder="Text...">
</textarea>
<input type="submit" class="send" value="Send">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
.bio{
display: block;
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: auto;
}

.send{
display: block;
margin-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Place the submit button outside the form but reference the form using the form's I'd property

```
<div>

<form action="..." method="..." Id="form-id">
.
.
.
</form>
  <button type="submit" form="form-id">Submit</button>

</div>
```